# DNS Always Getting Non-Authoritative Answer

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm trying to get an authoritative answer on a DNS query. I've used nslookup using "set querytype=ns" to get the primary name server, which returned the following:

```
yesecommerce.com
        primary name server = ns.123-reg.co.uk
        responsible mail addr = hostmaster.yesecommerce.com
        serial  = 2011091001
        refresh = 86400 (1 day)
        retry   = 3600 (1 hour)
        expire  = 1209600 (14 days)
        default TTL = 14400 (4 hours)
```

However when I then try "nslookup www.yesecommerce.com ns.123-reg.co.uk" I get the following:

```
Server:  ns.123-reg.co.uk
Address:  212.67.202.2

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    www.yesecommerce.com
Address:  95.154.207.68
```

I though that when querying the primary nameserver I would receive an authoritative answer and i'm confused as to why not - any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Upvoted for not obfuscating names/IPs :)

Answer (score 5):

I don't:

```
[me@risby me]$ nslookup www.yesecommerce.com ns.123-reg.co.uk
Server:         ns.123-reg.co.uk
Address:        212.67.202.2#53

Name:   www.yesecommerce.com
Address: 92.19.219.18
```

Some ISPs do transparent proxying of DNS requests; it may be that your ISP is amongst them.  The fact that we get consistently different A records returned points in that direction, too.

Comment: Thanks for the help - I ran a DNS leak test here - https://www.dnsleaktest.com/ - and it came up with OpenDNS which is what our SBS 2008 server is set to use as the forwarder, could the SBS server be the cause of the problem then? The different IP address is a change I just made to check if our system would pick up a change in IP address (it seems not to be)

Comment: I don't know, because I don't know SBS at all.  I **do** think it's highly significant that I don't see the non-authoritative flag being set, but I can't say what might be causing it without doing some much more precise experimentation.

Comment: Me either really - but I think that is where the problem lies, thanks for your input though, at least i', not going mad!

Comment: SBS can't be the problem if you're querying the name server directly. Also, nslookup works fine for me when querying the name server directly.

Comment: @joeqwerty it can if the SBS server is doing the transparent DNS proxying; I have no idea if it is, because I know nothing about it.  Thanks for confirming that you, too, get an authoritative answer; it adds to my conviction that *something* in his DNS chain-of-transmission is messing with that query, directed though it may be.

Comment: I don't know what a transparent DNS proxy is, but if the OP queries the authoritative name server directly (as he did with nslookup) I don't see how it could possibly be the SBS server.

Comment: It's a device that intercepts DNS requests, answers them from its own caches, but pretends the answer came from the queried server.  ISPs are fond of them, because it lets them return business-specific answers (ie, advertising pages) to mistyped DNS requests.  Sysadmins, not so much.

Comment: @joeqwerty - If you can't trust DNS, you can't be sure you're talking to the authoritative name server directly if you refer to it by name :)

Comment: Both, I don't think it's a transparent DNS issue, the dnsleaktest.com results pretty mcuh confirm that (I think) - it's very strange, I would have thought nslookup using the server option would bypass anything on this network, but yeah you're right something is messing with it. I'll have to dig a little deeper. It does seem to be some kind of caching thing as it's only when an A-record IP address is changed that this issue happens.